# How to add authorization to Response.Header?

Tags: asp.net, json, reactjs, asp.net-authorization

I have the following controller function:

```
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Login(string username, string password)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
        var res = await _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, password, false);

        if (res.Succeeded)
        {
            var msg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            msg.Headers.Add("Authorization", JwtManager.GenerateToken(username));
            return msg;
        }
        else
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);// Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new object());
    }
```

In the reducer in React I have this:

```
let fetchTask = fetch('http://localhost:25565/api/mediaengine/login?username=' + userName + '&password=' + password)

            .then(response => {
                var k = response.headers.get("Authorization");
                var l = 0;
            })
            .catch(e => {
            });
        addTask(fetchTask);
```

For some reason response.headers.get("Authorization") is coming back null..

Answer (score 1):

You should return the response from the api. This can be done with the HttpResponseMessage class

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Login(string username, string password)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
    var res = await _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, password, false);

    if(res.Succeeded)
    {
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new object());
        response.Headers.Add("Authorization", JwtManager.GenerateToken(username));
        return response;
    }else
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new object());
}
```

Comment: I edited my question to take your answer into account, I had to do things slightly differently (new HttpResponseMessage instead of Request.CreateResponse which doesn't exist, possibly because I'm using asp.net core...)

Comment: @tweetypi ok, yes if you are using .net core my answer needs to be updated. But, the concept is the same. If you still don't get the header in the response, check if some middleware in your response pipeline is clearing the headers after your controller method is invoked. Check in the startup